# Nuxt Router Push without Changing Page

Tags: vue.js, nuxt.js

I have a homepage which is paginated, though when clicking "Next Page" it seems to be looking for a page named `/page/1`. Is there a way to paginate the `index.vue` page without creating a brand new page?

I've currently implemented the following on @click.

```
  this.$router.push({
    path: '/' + this.page,
    query: { },
  })
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can have dynamic parameters.

For example

url.com/1

url.com/2

So if your home page is `index.vue`, you need to create a vue file next to it for a dynamic parameter with name after an underscore, for example `_id.vue`

So the param after the root URL will be mapped to this page.

[For more resources about file system and routing in `NUXT`](https://nuxtjs.org/docs/features/file-system-routing/)